# How to flatten data on Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an application where users post products inside categories. I am using firebase and I am trying to flatten the data on the database but I am not sure about the connections of the posts with the categories.

Here is the database design:

```
"categories": {
  "category1": {
     "id": "1",
     "name":  "computers"  
   },
  "category2": {
     "id": "2",
     "name":  "Furniture"  
    },
  "category3: {
    "id": "3",
    "names":  "Books" 
   },
}
"users":{
  "email": "test@gmail.com"       
  "posts": {
    "post1": {
       "id": "1"
       "title": "Selling my guitar”,
       "categories": {
         "category1": "true"
        }
      }
  }
```

**Edit:** Maybe smth like this

```
"categories": {
  "category1": {
     "id": "1",
     "name":  "computers",
     "posts": {
        "post1": true
     }
   },
  "category2": {
     "id": "2",
     "name":  "Furniture"
   },
  "category3": {
    "id": "3",
    "names":  "Books"
   },
}
"users": {
  "userid1": {
    "email": "test@gmail.com" ,
    "posts": {
      "post1": "true"
    }
  }
 },

 "posts": {
    "post1": {
       "id": "1",
       "title": "Selling my guitar",
       "users": {
         "user1" : "true"
       },
       "categories": {
         "category1": "true"
        }
      }
  }
```

So from what I learnt I know posts should be a separate entity but then I am not sure how to connect them.

Let me know how can I improve this database.

Answer (score 3):

Flattening data means that you don't mix entity types. If you look at your current `/users` node, you now information about the user there (their email address) and a list of nodes. Those are two distinct entity types and should normally be in separate top-level lists.

```
"categories": {
  "category1": {
     "id": "1",
     "name":  "computers"  
   },
  "category2": {
     "id": "2",
     "name":  "Furniture"  
    },
  "category3: {
    "id": "3",
    "names":  "Books" 
   },
}
"users":{
  "userid1": {
    "email": "test@gmail.com"       
  }
 },
 "posts": {
    "post1": {
       "id": "1"
       "title": "Selling my guitar”,
       "categories": {
         "category1": "true"
        }
      }
  }
```

Comment: What about the connection of users with posts. Users will create those posts . 
On my app I should be able to query posts per user and posts per category.

Comment: I edited my post. According your response and the needs of my app should look like that. 
I should be able to query posts, posts by category, and posts by user .
Thank you for the input

Comment: It all depends on the use-cases of your app, and is rather broad even then. I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and (if you have a SQL background) watching [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).