# Retrieving all the passenger id (user id) inside the driver's passengerRequest node in Firebase and Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrieve and convert it to strings the UserIDs that are being saved within the driver's passengerRequest like in this picture:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztATh.jpg

here is my getAssignPassenger

```
private void getAssignedPassenger() {
    String driverID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Driver").child(driverID).child("passengerRequest");
    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                passengerID = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                getAssignPassengerPickUpLocation();
            }else{
                passengerID = "";
                if(pickupMarker !=null){
                    pickupMarker.remove();
                }
                if(AssignPassengerPickupLocationListener!= null){
                AssignPassengerPickupLocationref.removeEventListener(AssignPassengerPickupLocationListener);
            }}
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

my problem is here in this block

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Driver").child(driverID).child("passengerRequest");
    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                passengerID = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                getAssignPassengerPickUpLocation();
```

in the passengerID it should retrieve every userIDs that are saved in there...
how do I that?

Next problem is... IF I successfully retrieved the userIDs and how do I continue it in finding their location, here is picture of the node:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kvbhi.jpg

I already started the codes for it

here is my getAssignPassengerLocation

```
private void getAssignPassengerPickUpLocation() {

    AssignPassengerPickupLocationref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("passengerRequest").child(passengerID).child("l");
    AssignPassengerPickupLocationListener = AssignPassengerPickupLocationref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()&&!passengerID.equals("")) {
                List<Object> map = (List<Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                double locationLat = 0;
                double locationLong = 0;

                if (map.get(0) != null) {
                    locationLat = Double.parseDouble(map.get(0).toString());
                }
                if (map.get(1) != null) {
                    locationLong = Double.parseDouble(map.get(1).toString());
                }
                LatLng driverLatLng = new LatLng(locationLat, locationLong);

                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(driverLatLng).title("Pickup Location").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_pickup_marker)));
```

what should I do in this block

```
AssignPassengerPickupLocationref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("passengerRequest").child(passengerID).child("l");
    AssignPassengerPickupLocationListener = AssignPassengerPickupLocationref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()&&!passengerID.equals("")) {
                List<Object> map = (List<Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                double locationLat = 0;
                double locationLong = 0;
```

is it possible to store the nodes in an Array String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For the first one**

You have to get snapshot children inside snapshot

```
private void getAssignedPassenger() {
    String driverID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Driver").child(driverID).child("passengerRequest");
    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                List<String> passengerIdList = new ArrayList()
                for (DataSnapshot passenger Snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String passengerId = passenger.getKey()
                    passengerIdList.add(passengerId)
                }
                getAssignPassengerPickUpLocation();
            }else{
                passengerID = "";
                if(pickupMarker !=null){
                    pickupMarker.remove();
                }
                if(AssignPassengerPickupLocationListener!= null){
                AssignPassengerPickupLocationref.removeEventListener(AssignPassengerPickupLocationListener);
            }}
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

**For the second one**

Actually you have to keep location same position as 'destination' instead of query in another children.

But why you need to get all users request location at the same time or inside your activity contain all users request location in one activity?

For more information:

**Read and write lists**

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data

and

**How to structured NoSQL**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_hR4K4auoQ

Comment: For the second one:  'destination'(String only) is where the passenger wants to go, in the passengerRequest node it is their current location, it will show on the DriverMap where is the marker of their current location for pickup, is it possible to display at the same time all the markers where they are in their current location?

Comment: I used geoFire to store the locations

Comment: Actually you can do that just loop on passengerIdList, get their location and add marker to the map one by one but i suggest to keep their location same level as destination'(String only) that mean the passenger (who sent location) need to write second node. Another approach is the passenger just update their location only one place ( in the passengerRequest ) but let cloud functions triggered when passenger have update location and write to another path that where driver need.

Comment: If im going to loop it, the second one would look the first one that you made? also the location in the passengerRequest is only in one place and only triggered once unless the passenger stopped/cancelled the request

Comment: It's a little bit different. The first one that i made that mean you got every id in single query. You just loop to get each id to get all of passenger id but for second one it mean you have to to query their location by their id from passengerRequest one by one so you have multiple query from firebase. Is passenger location are realtime update? if not it will be fine to duplicate passenger location same level as destination.

Comment: Realtime update is like when I tap the button ("Find Bus") it will automatically put marker on your current location and create a node in the passengerRequest where the location is stored

Comment: location in passengerRequest is FROM and destination is TO. FROM: Phillipines(location) TO: destination it is something like this

Comment: Is from and to are static or it able to change?

Comment: You should keep it in the same even it is able to change later or not.
example destination you should keep name, lat, long in this node also passenger location as well because firebase recommended to flatten your data. here is some example how to flattening data.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47444173/how-to-flatten-data-on-firebase

Comment: It can be changed

Comment: Sorry for not answering quickly the passengerRequest in every driver is the one that driver will going to pickup ,... The passengerRequest node outside is the liat of available passengers

Comment: So you just keep information that you need in passengerRequest-> passengerId -> (keep here) instead of keep it separately or whatever node you want that will be able to get 'from coordinate' and 'to coordinate' only in a single query.

Comment: Can you review my codes from both DriverMap and PassengerMap? and also I'm sorry for what am I going to ask, can I have your email, so I can contact you and if not I wil ask questiona here

Comment: same as my stack username plus @gmail.com